# HTTP 500 on Podio GET item

Tags: podio

When fetching `GET https://api.podio.com/item/1259778758` (other items work fine), I get the following error:

```
HTTP 500
```

with response body:

```
{
"error_parameters": {},
"error_detail": null,
"error_propagate": false,
"request": {
    "url": "http://api.podio.com/item/1259778758",
    "query_string": "",
    "method": "GET"
},
"error_description": "An unexpected error occured during execution",
"error": "unexpected"
}
```

I assume this is due to some field value, but cannot figure this out. Can you please check an fix this?

Additional notes:

1. It is not possible to open this item in the browser as well
2. The filter operation in the API fails as well when this item is in the result.

Comment: ` For non-programming questions please refer to Podio's Help Centre directly `

Comment: This is an API related question - Citrix-Podio Help Center referred to Stackoverflow for this..!

Comment: Well, other items work fine. So the API is working, it's just a particular result is not. And nobody can see that on the backend execpt podio. They refereed you here probably via an automated script. Get back to them!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this should be escalated with Podio technical support.

Comment: Can you please do this?